# Oracle text search with special character

Tags: sql, oracle, text-search

I haved index as below;

```
create index cidx_column1 on MY_TABLE(column1) indextype is ctxsys.CTXCAT;

SELECT
from 
  MY_TABLE
WHERE catsearch(column1, '$*', null)  > 0 and taken > 
to_date('01/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy')
```

I have a column that can have special character. How do i list all the data that has special character like '$' sign?. Above statement is returning nothing and i can confirm that "column1" has a text $50 and so on.

I want to use oracle text based search not like operator.

Your help or any suggestion in this regard is highly appreciated.

Thanks
Ravan

Comment: I'm not familiar with Oracle Text but it seems to be some kind of full text search facility. If so, it's possibly not designed to find random characters.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below query. You can use `LIKE` or `INSTR`

```
SELECT
from 
  MY_TABLE
WHERE column1 like '%$%' and taken > 
to_date('01/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

or

```
SELECT
from 
MY_TABLE
WHERE instr(column1, '$') > 0 and taken > 
to_date('01/01/2020','dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Comment: Sorry Jim this is not what i wanted. i want to use textsearch available in oracle not like operator

Comment: Hey Jim,
Can you please replace "*" from column1 in above query. Also thanks for editing my query

Comment: Then you may not have `$` symbol in your column. I have provided you the query using `instr` as well. Please use that and confirm if its working

Comment: Where do you want to replace `*`?

Comment: i wanted to know if there is way to add special character in catsearch method

Comment: Catsearch can be used when you use `CTXCAT` index, which provides you a good perfomance. If not LIKE and INSTR operator will be more helpful

Comment: Please try with braces.  WHERE catsearch(column1, '{$}', null)  > 0 and taken > .